# Why can't it print some message

Tags: ios, swift

I used loop to create some buttons, and I added Listener on them in the loop ,it should execute the "get()"function and output the button's label in console,but why it can't work?

```
func setupGameBoard() {
    for i in 0..<2 {
        if i == 1 {
            initialX = CGFloat(horizontalTilePadding)
            initialY = verticalTilePadding!
        }
        else {
            initialX = CGFloat(horizontalTilePadding)
            initialY = CGFloat(verticalTilePadding!)
        }

        var tileX = initialX
        var tileY = initialY

        for j in 0..<dimension {
            tileX = initialX
            for k in 0..<colomn {
               let tile = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(tileX, tileY,tileWidth,tileWidth))
                tile.setTitle("a", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                tile.addTarget(self, action: Selector("get:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
                ButtonArray.append(tile)

                tile.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                if(i == 0){
                    TopView?.addSubview(tile)
                }
                else {
                    ButtomView?.addSubview(tile)
                }
                tileX += tileWidth+horizontalTilePadding
            }
            tileY += tileWidth+verticalTilePadding!
        }
    }
}

func get(button : UIButton) {
    print(button.titleForState(.Normal), appendNewline: false)
}
```

Comment: did my answer help you? or you are still not able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Quite a common problem, I suggest you try setting:

```
TopView?.userInteractionEnabled = false
BottomView?.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

Please let me know if that helps.